# Error while executing "fastlane provision" command

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, fastlane

I'm trying to integrate FastLane for automatic app submission to app store. I am following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/116065/fastlane-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial, but while Creating Certificates and Provisioning Profiles using "fastlane provision" command I'm getting below issues.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- gh_inspector (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane_core-0.47.0/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:92:in `show_github_issues'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane_core-0.47.0/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:68:in `handle_unknown_error!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane_core-0.47.0/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:47:in `rescue in run!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane_core-0.47.0/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:50:in `run!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.32.1/bin/fastlane:136:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.32.1/bin/fastlane:142:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I've added [a request](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5191) to the fastlane team to get some help with the issue. Please upvote if you've run into the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Gyuri's [Request](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5191)

```
    $sudo gem update gh_inspector
```

This is solve my problem on El Capitan.